# How do you convert string to bolean in visual studio c# windowform

Tags: c#

Below are my code extractStringValue and extractFloatValue are correct

```
private string extractStringValue(string strData, string ID)
        {
            string result = strData.Substring(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
            return result;
        }
        private float extractFloatValue(string strData, string ID)
        {
            return (float.Parse(extractStringValue(strData, ID)));
        }
```

Below  code private bool extractBoolValue(string strData, string ID) is wrong

How do i change the below code to make it work? The error is at the SubString. i am unable to change subString to subBolean

```
private bool extractBoolValue(string strData, string ID)
    {

        bool result = strData.SubString(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that result is "true" or "false" then there are a few of options:

```
string result = strData.SubString(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
return Boolean.Parse(result);
```

or:

```
string result = strData.SubString(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
```

or:

```
string result = strData.SubString(strData.IndexOf(ID) + ID.Length);
return result.ToLower() == "true";
```